# Insert Captcha Code info Any Form (Created of Plugin)

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7, captcha

I am looking for best option on Captcha.  Plugin's don't seem to be the answer because this is a custom form for the theme I am using. Unfortunately, they don't offer any spam protection.  The form is heavily styled so I do not want to start from scratch.  I do have access to the contact form code and can plug one right in.

I can't imagine I am the only one with this issue.  Doing a Google search hasn't been very insightful as well.

Is my best option to find a plugin or add custom code?  if so - can I do some kind of Javascript only protection? I'd rather not integrate it with PHP unless I have to...

Comment: Use a slider captcha, easy to integrate and stops bot spam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say this question is *mostly* off-topic since it's not WordPress-specific. Mostly, because the majority of PHP solutions out there use sessions, which will not work out-of-the-box in WordPress.

[Google search](https://www.google.ca/#hl=en&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=Captcha+tutorial+without+session&oq=Captcha+tutorial+without+session&fp=ac45f88f2047e900) actually handles this question quite well. Have a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472/practical-non-image-based-captcha-approaches) for nice techniques.

Finally, Contact Form 7 [has Captcha built-in](http://contactform7.com/captcha/).